# Warning in LongCat :JSONException

Tags: android, json

This is the code in eclipse:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(getRequest(myUrl));
JSONArray jArray = j.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    sret += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("NO_CUST").toString();
}
```

This is the code in PHP:

```
$result = mssql_query($query, $conn) or die('Errorquery:  '.$query);

$rows = array();
while ($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$data = "{data:".json_encode($rows)."}";
echo $data;
```

Logcat :

```
03-07 16:05:58.504: W/System.err(821): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Why?

Comment: put your full logcat and can you put url?

Comment: the last line of php code is echo $data. Can you please add the php log? I mean the printed value of data.

Comment: @shaiful:
please write that code...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$data = "{data:".json_encode($rows)."}";
echo $data;
```

use

```
print(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: I've changed the code but still find the same warning in logcat