# Warning in LongCat :JSONException in android

Tags: android, json

This code in eclipse:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(getRequest(MyUrl));

    JSONArray jArray = j.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        sret += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("I_Date").toString();

    }
    txtResult.setText(sret);
```

This code in PHP:

```
$result = mssql_query($query, $connect) or die('Errorquery:  '.$query);
$rows = array();
while ($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$data = "{data:".json_encode($rows)."}";

echo $data;
```

Why `txtResult=null` and any Warning in LongCat

```
03-07 16:56:15.194: W/System.err(906): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Where are problems?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echo "$data".. use this print(json_encode($data));.. i think this works

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599053/warning-in-longcat-jsonexception